# applescript (10.9) Can’t make alias into type specifier

Tags: macos, applescript

The below applescript registers `AppUninstaller.scpt` as folder action to Trash folder.
Registering the folder action script works fine in Mac OSX 10.7 and 10.8.

In 10.9, I get the error "***Attach error System Events got an error: Can’t make alias "Macintosh HD:Users:[username]:.Trash:" into type specifier.*"**

The error occurs while executing this statement

```
 attach action to _trashFolder using _uninstallerScriptPath
```

the complete script is below.

```
on run
    tell utils

        init()
        registerFolderAction()

    end tell
end run


script utils
      property _uninstallerScript : "AppUninstaller.scpt"
      property _resRelativePath : ":Applications:TestDemo.app:Contents:Resources:"
      property _folderActionScriptRelativePath : "Scripts:Folder Action Scripts"

      global _resPath
      global _trashFolder
      global _uninstallerScriptPath

      on init()
                  -- Setup paths
                set _trashFolder to path to trash folder

                set _uninstallerScriptPath to getUninstallerScript()

                  -- Add boot disk name to App relative path
                tell application "Finder"
                          set startupDisk to (name of startup disk)
                          set _resPath to startupDisk & _resRelativePath
                end tell

                set scriptFolderPath to getScriptPath()

             -- Copy folder action script file from appbundle to scripts folder
             copyScript()

      end init

      on registerFolderAction()
                try
                     tell application "System Events"
                          set folder actions enabled to true
                          log _uninstallerScriptPath

                          -- problem with below statement.
                          attach action to _trashFolder using _uninstallerScriptPath

                          end tell
                on error msg
                          display dialog "Attach error " & msg
                end try

      end registerFolderAction

      on getScriptPath()
                return ((path to library folder from user domain) as string) & _folderActionScriptRelativePath
      end getScriptPath

      on getUninstallerScript()
                return getScriptPath() & ":" & _uninstallerScript
      end getUninstallerScript

      -- copying the script inside app bundle into scripts folder.
      on copyScript()
                tell application "Finder"
                          set srcFile to _resPath & _uninstallerScript
                          set dstFile to my getScriptPath()

                          log "Src File " & srcFile & " dstFolder " & dstFile
                          duplicate file srcFile to dstFile with replacing
                end tell
      end copyScript

end script
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error (and after testing myself) it seems that in pre-Mavericks systems the first argument of `attach action to` command is properly coerced into a file/folder object specifier when the argument is an alias. In Mavericks this coercion somehow doesn't happen and an error will occur because the given argument is not an object/type specifier but an alias class. The first argument of `attach action to` needs to be an object/type specifier so you can solve your problem by forcing the coercion when the command is called.

```
attach action to folder (_trashFolder as text) using _uninstallerScriptPath
```

You can do the same with argument `using`